# IPad keyboard hides selection list

Tags: ipad

I've got a web page targeted to iPad. It contains a textarea followed by a dropdown. The problem is when a user moves focus from the textarea to the dropdown the keyboard does not hide and overlaps with opened drop down list hiding it (or the list appears too short because of the keyboard).

Did anybody face it? What do you suggest?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A basic way that I've countered this problem is by placing a method in the view controller so when the user hits the return key, it should hide the keyboard. The method is called automatically. However, I've only done this for iPhone applications. The solution may not work for the iPad

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {

if (theTextField == yourTextField) {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}

return YES;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mean an ordinary web page for internal safari without any other coding.